# jQuery: how to optimize/clean this basic animation code?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm trying to make hand animation to draw shape, it works fine, but the code looks long and non-professional. any solutions to make this animation short and professional?

here's an example, my actual animation is too long but has same idea:

```
$(hand).animate({ top : 30, left : 255 }, function(){
  $(hand).animate({ top : 130, left : 250 }, function(){
    $(hand).animate({ top : 140, left : 265 }, function(){
        $(an_element).fadeOut();
    });
  });
});
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write it as this:

```
$(hand)
    .animate({ top : 30, left : 255 })
    .animate({ top : 130, left : 250 })
    .animate({ top : 140, left : 265 }, function(){
        $(an_element).fadeOut();
    });
```

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/PL8fK/)

---

## Update:

You can write it like this as well:

```
handCoorArr = [ [30,255], [130,250], [140,265] ];

for (i=0;i<handCoorArr.length;i++)
{
    $(hand).animate({top:handCoorArr[i][0],left:handCoorArr[i][1]});
}
/* 400 is the default animation speed */
$(an_element).delay(400*handCoorArr.length).fadeOut();
```

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/6VFSB/)

---

## Update 2:

With specific delay for each step of the animation

```
handCoorArr = [ [30,255,50], [130,250,800], [140,265,500] ];

for (i=0;i<handCoorArr.length;i++)
{
    $(hand).animate({top:handCoorArr[i][0],left:handCoorArr[i][1]},handCoorArr[i][2]);
}
handDelay=0;
$.each($.map(handCoorArr, function(v,i){return v[2]}),function(){handDelay+=this;});
$(an_element).delay(handDelay).fadeOut();
```

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/f83hc/)

Comment: thank's, that's a good way to reduce lines, but still non-professional way :) my code is too long and need a dynamic function, maybe add top & left values to an array and retrieve them dynamically, i don't now.

Comment: In your demo you have `hand = $("#hand");` and then `$(hand).animate ...` Looks like you are wrapping your element in jQuery twice. Shouldn't it be `hand.animate ...` ?

Comment: @zgood Oh you're right! But that is just what OP is using in his original code so it doesn't really matter as he isn't going to use `hand = $("#hand")`. I just needed dummy elements.

Comment: amazing! last thing, I added an Int (eg. 50) as "speed" for each animation instead of the default [30,255,50] and I used the handCoorArr[i][2] to call it, it works great :) but what about the fade delay in this case? you get it?